# Script python duplicar filas

Tags: python, csv, script

Tengo un archivo CSV del estilo siguiente:

[image: Tabla]

Necesito hacer uns cript que duplique la fila en el caso de que en la columna length aparezcan varios valores separados por coma.
Cada fila creada debe tomar uno de estos valores.
Ejemplo del resultado deseado:
[image: Tabla2]

A ver si alguien puede arrojar algo de luz sobre esto porque me estoy comiendo la cabeza bastante tiempo.

Muchas gracias!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Una forma muy simple es usar el módulo *csv* de la biblioteca estándar y luego por cada fila aplicar `str.split` sobre la columna `Length` para separar por las posibles comas:

```
import csv


with open("datos.csv") as csv_in, open("datos_out.csv", "w") as csv_out:
    reader = csv.reader(csv_in, delimiter=";")
    writer = csv.writer(csv_out, delimiter=";")
    for row in reader:
        for length in row[-1].split(", "):
            writer.writerow((*row[:-1], length))
```

Para un csv como el siguiente:

> Company Name;Product Name;Dista Size(F);Length
>   Penumbra, Inc.(Neuro);4MAX DDC;4.3;130
>   Penumbra, Inc.(Neuro);4MAX DDC;5;115,125
>   Medtronic;Apollo Onyx Delibery Micro Catheter;1.5;165
>   Asahi Intecc USA, Inc.;Asahi Caravel;1.4;135,150
>   Asahi Intecc USA, Inc.;Asahi Corsair;1.3;135,150
>   Asahi Intecc USA, Inc.;Asahi Corsair Pro;1.3;135,150

Obtenemos:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La principal ventaja, aparte de solo usar Python estándar, es que grcias al uso de iteradores no se requiere cargar ninguno de los csv en memoria al completo simultáneamente, a la par que se va leyendo el csv de entrada se va creando el de salida.

Answer (score 0):

A partir de Pandas **>= 0.25**, hay una manera directa y muy sencilla. Partiendo de los datos de ejemplo la respuesta anterior:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('datos.csv', sep = ';')
df
    Company Name            Product Name            Data Size(F) Length
0   Penumbra, Inc.(Neuro)   4MAX DDC                4.3          130
1   Penumbra, Inc.(Neuro)   4MAX DDC                5.0          115,125
2   Medtronic   Apollo Onyx Delibery Micro Catheter 1.5          165
3   Asahi Intecc USA, Inc.  Asahi Caravel           1.4          135,150
4   Asahi Intecc USA, Inc.  Asahi Corsair           1.3          135,150
5   Asahi Intecc USA, Inc.  Asahi Corsair Pro       1.3          135,150
```

Primero con `.assign()`, modificamos la columna Lengh para hacer el split por la coma, y luego con el metodo [.explode()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html#pandas.DataFrame.explode) expandimos el dataframe:

```
df = df.assign(Length=a['Length'].str.split(',')).explode('Length').reset_index(drop = True)
df

    Company Name            Product Name            Data Size(F) Length
0   Penumbra, Inc.(Neuro)   4MAX DDC                4.3          130
1   Penumbra, Inc.(Neuro)   4MAX DDC                5.0          115
2   Penumbra, Inc.(Neuro)   4MAX DDC                5.0          125
3   Medtronic   Apollo Onyx Delibery Micro Catheter 1.5          165
4   Asahi Intecc USA, Inc.  Asahi Caravel           1.4          135
5   Asahi Intecc USA, Inc.  Asahi Caravel           1.4          150
6   Asahi Intecc USA, Inc.  Asahi Corsair           1.3          135
7   Asahi Intecc USA, Inc.  Asahi Corsair           1.3          150
8   Asahi Intecc USA, Inc.  Asahi Corsair Pro       1.3          135
9   Asahi Intecc USA, Inc.  Asahi Corsair Pro       1.3          150
```

Asi de simple, en una linea y sin for loops. Solo quedaria guardar el csv:

```
df.to_csv('datos.out', sep=';')
```